# apache 2.4.10 times on file upload. RequestReadTimeout does not increase time

Tags: apache-2.4, timeout, upload

Versions: Apache/2.4.10 (Raspbian) PHP/5.6.30-0+deb8u1 OpenSSL/1.0.1t

From linux console, testing the ssl timeout:

```
time openssl s_client -connect x.y.z:443
...
  Start Time: 1504204638
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
(delay  of about 20 secs)
​----​
read:errno=0

real    0m20.903s
user    0m0.050s
sys     0m0.000s
```

When the above test was done, error log shows (in debug level setting)

```
[2017-08-31 12:00:46] [ssl:info] [client 192.168.1.1:38094] AH01964: Connection to child 0 established (server x.y.z:443)
[2017-08-31 12:00:46] [ssl:debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1936): [client 192.168.1.1:38094] AH02645: Server name not provided via TLS extension (using default/first virtual host)
[2017-08-31 12:00:46] [ssl:debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1841): [client 192.168.1.1:38094] AH02041: Protocol: TLSv1.2, Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits)
```

​(​Note the 21 sec delay  (apparently openssl has a 20 sec hard coded delay)​  )​

```
[2017-08-31 12:01:07] [reqtimeout:info] [client 192.168.1.1:38094] AH01382: Request header read timeout
[2017-08-31 12:01:07] [ssl:info] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 192.168.1.1:38094] AH01991: SSL input filter read failed.
[2017-08-31 12:01:07] [ssl:debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1004): [client 192.168.1.1:38094] AH02001: Connection closed to child 0 with standard shutdown (server x.y.z:443)
```

---

Image upload , even small files, times out after about 15 secs, independent of the following (see two settings tried)

```
# the following is an expt, setting very low to see if this statement has any effect at all. We get time out after 15 secs, for any setting.
#RequestReadTimeout header=5 body=9

RequestReadTimeout header=60-100,MinRate=50 body=80,MinRate=50
```

For the actual timeouts during timeout in the apache​ 2.4​ error.log
 (​W​ith either of the above settings,the time out is pretty much the same​ ​15 sec.​; only one log is shown below)​​

```
[2017-08-31 12:06:52] [authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 192.168.1.1:52406] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer ...
```

(Note authorization was granted.  Delay between above/below about 15sec!​)​

```
[2017-08-31 12:07:07] [reqtimeout:info] [client 192.168.1.1:52406] AH01382: Request header read timeout
[2017-08-31 12:07:07] [ssl:info] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 192.168.1.1:52406] AH01991: SSL input filter read failed.
[2017-08-31 12:07:07] [ssl:debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1004): [client 192.168.1.1:52406] AH02001: Connection closed to child 2 with standardshutdown (server x.y.z:443)
```